# Retrieve rows that appears more than one time

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Let's say that I have table A and table B, the relationship between them is 1 to many, how do I retrieve only the rows which the A PK appears **more than once?** in the table B as a FK? I have no idea how could I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the `B` rows and count them in a subquery for `A`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
WHERE  A.pk IN (SELECT   fk
                FROM     B
                GROUP BY fk
                HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT fkey, count(*) FROM B WHERE fkey IN (SELECT pkey FROM A)  GROUP BY fkey HAVING count(*) > 1;